# How to replace two lines of text in file using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I need to replace two string lines in a text file. 
I wrote a script that replace one string:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem file name
Set infile=file.txt

rem what to find
Set find=123

rem value to replace
Set replace=321

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set COUNT=0
for /F "tokens=* delims=," %%n in (!infile!) do (
set LINE=%%n
set TMPR=!LINE:%find%=%replace%!
Echo !TMPR!>>tmp.txt
)
move tmp.txt %infile%
pause
```

How to modify it to replace 2 lines at once? I mean 'find' to 'replace' and 'find2' to 'replace2'?

Comment: after your `set TMPR=...`, add `set TMPR=!TMPR:%find2%=%replace2%!`

Comment: @Stephan It just replaces the second line and not the first one.

Comment: How that? your existing code replaces the first line, right? Add my line where I said to replace the second one.

Comment: Ok, there is a misunderstanding ) With your code yes it replaces two strings when they are equal. But I want other: I have strings 'abc' and 'def', I want them to be replaced to '123' and '456' respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after your `set TMPR=...`, add `set TMPR=!TMPR:%find2%=%replace2%!`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
del tmp.txt
rem file name
Set infile=file.txt

rem what to find
Set find=abc
set find2=def

rem value to replace
Set replace=123
set replace2=456

for /F "tokens=* delims=," %%n in (!infile!) do (
set LINE=%%n
set TMPR=!LINE:%find%=%replace%!
set TMPR=!TMPR:%find2%=%replace2%!
Echo !TMPR!>>tmp.txt
)
type tmp.txt
```

file.txt:

```
aaa
abc
bbb
def
ccc
xxxabcyyy
uuudefvvv
nnnabcdefmmm
```

Output:

```
aaa
123
bbb
456
ccc
xxx123yyy
uuu456vvv
nnn123456mmm
```

Answer (score -1):

Is there no other way to pass 2 value into a function which searches for a property string and replaces the value?
like:

## code:

```
CALL :modify prop.first.name , myName
CALL :modify prop.last.name , myLastName
:modify

set "source=srcFile.txt"
set "target=tmpFile.txt"

set property=%~1
set value=%~2

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ('findstr /B "^" %source%') do (
  set line=%%b
  if defined line echo !line:%property%=%property%=%value%!
)
) > %target%
 endlocal
```

## source file looks like:

prop.first.name=firstname

prop.last.name=lastname

prop.pssw.word=password

prop.url.link=alink

## need to replace value after "=" equal sign to an input

idea is to call a generic function 4 times with different parameters